# iOS MPVolumeView breaks based on AudioSession Mode

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on a VoIP app, that uses an MPVolumeView to allow the user to adjust the system volume.  This all worked fine and dandy until iOS 9.1 came out.  Then I found that if I set the `AVAudioSession` mode to `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` the `MPVolumeView` slider broke.  (That is the slider no longer adjusted the system volume.)  If I changed the mode to `AvAudioSessionModeDefault` the `MPVolumeView` would work as expected, but I the mic would record the audio coming from the iPad's speaker.  (In other words the voice processing was turned off--which I need for the VoIP calls.)  Previous to iOS 9.1 I could set the AudioSession mode to `AVAudioSessionModeDefault` and then in the AudioComponentDescription set the componentSubType to `kAudioUnitSubType_VoiceProcessingIO` and everything worked fine.  Unfortunately that no longer seems the case.  Does anyone know how to keep voice processing AND have MPVolumeView work post iOS 9.1?

Here is the code where I set the AVAudioSession:

```
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

    // Make sure the session on this thread matches.
    AVAudioSession *audioSession = [AVAudioSession sharedInstance];
    [audioSession setCategory:AVAudioSessionCategoryPlayAndRecord withOptions:AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionMixWithOthers | AVAudioSessionCategoryOptionAllowBluetooth error:nil];

    // Here is the main connundrum: I want to set AVAudioSessionModeDefault so that the MPVolumeView will work,
    // but when I do that the mic picks up the audio from the speaker and plays it back creating an unwanted feeback loop.
    // If I set the mode to AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat the voice processing (primarily the AEC) fixes the feeback loop,
    // but then the MPVolumeView no longers works.  (It no longer adjusts the system volume.
    //Question: How can I have BOTH the voice processing AND the MPVolumeView adjust the system volume?
    if(!appDelegate.viewController.voiceChatMode)
        [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeDefault error:nil];
    else
        [audioSession setMode:AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat error:nil];

    [audioSession setPreferredIOBufferDuration:0.005 error:nil];
    [audioSession setActive:YES error:nil];
```

Comment: The code in your question works fine on iOS 9.2 (`MPVolumeView` is enabled when  `AVAudioSessionModeVoiceChat` mode is set). Does there need to be an active recording to reproduce the problem?

Comment: Probably.  In my sample project I have it recording audio and playing it back out the speaker, but it also is a problem when I have a VoIP app record voice audio and play audio from another user.  Do you have an example of it working? I ask because my simple test failed to work.

Comment: The only example I have does exactly what you have in the above code snippet, sorry.

Comment: This continues to be an issue on iOS 13 using the voicePrompt mode.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After talking to Apple's Technical support this is they answer straight from the horse's mouth:

*According to Core Audio engineering, the issue with the MPVolumeView no longer adjusting the system's volume is a known issue (r. 17292753) that is currently logged in our bug database.*

*I'm afraid I don't know of any way around this.
Otherwise, with regard to VoIP support, it is recommended that chat apps not have a volume slider and instead rely on the phone’s volume buttons.*

So There you have it.  Hopefully they will fix it sometime soon...

Comment: Ran into the same problem lately. Looks like in April it's still not solved.